# Programatically trigger "Open revision history" from CKEditor5 revision history toolbar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I am currently using CKEditor5 Revision history feature in my project. I have a requirement to open the revision history programatically without using the toolbar option, is there any function or API methods to trigger the event and show the revision history changes.
Please find below images for reference.
[image]

[image]

I want to go to revision history as shown in image 2 programatically without using the dropdown option shown in image 1